# Date predicament in vb/asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Alright so i am building a daily sales goal that is based on last years sales on the exact same day of this year last year.

so for example today is monday, 05 2011 and to get the sales goal i would need to do monday, 04 2011 not monday 05 2011,

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: "today is monday, 05 2011" ; you should update your calendar or something...

Comment: How are you determining "exact same day of this year" if not by date?  Do you want the same WEEK of the year?  If so, assuming 1/1 is a partial week (which is almost guaranteed), do you count it as a full week?  Maybe you meant you want the same Monday based on number of Mondays that have occurred in the year? Your business requirements are incomplete...

Comment: yes same week same day, at first i was thinking of doing if today is the 130th day of the year i want the 130th day of last year but then leap years would be messed up

Comment: The 130th day of every year will be the same day, with respect to leap years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this additional info:

> yes same week same day, at first i was thinking of doing if today is the 130th day of the year i want the 130th day of last year but then leap years would be messed up

I would say take advantage of DateTime.DayOfYear, like so:

```
DateTime lastYear = DateTime.Parse("1/1/" + (DateTime.Now.Year - 1));

lastYear.AddDays(DateTime.Now.DayOfYear);
```

Edit for more VB:

```
Dim lastYear As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("1/1/" + (DateTime.Now.Year - 1).ToString())

lastYear.AddDays(DateTime.Now.DayOfYear)
```

Edit for explanation as requested:

We can call `DateTime.Now.DayOfYear` to find out what day we are in for the current year (for example today is the 94th day since 1/1/2011).  If we add 94 days to 1/1/2010, we should arrive at the 94th day of LAST year: 4/5/2010.

The first line of code gets us a date for 1/1/2010 by parsing out the string "1/1/2010".  The second line adds the number of days that have elapsed THIS YEAR, effectively counting 94 days from 1/1/2010.

Comment: i am using vb.net i dont  think there is a dump function

Comment: yay it worked thanks so much, but could you explain how it is working, that would be great and the fact you did it in 2 lines of code is crazy]

Comment: Glad it worked, added a small explanation.  Also, the Dump() function was from LINQPad.  It's very, very handy for proving out little snippets like this.  Check it out!

Comment: ahh this actually is what i stated could work but it doesnt, i cant go by the day of year, for example when i tryed the date 5/27/2011 which is a friday this year. but was a thursday last year, so i should have gotten 5/28/2010 and not 5/27/2010 ugh lol

Comment: i think i have to go by the week of the year and the day

Comment: what if i used the day of the year for example if january 3 is the 3rd day of the year and i divide it by 7 divide which would be .42 or the 1st week of the year which is also a monday, then i found the first week of last year and the day that it was a monday?

Comment: Dunno...  you can do anything you want, but you have to hammer out functional requirements before you try to do anything technical.  What does "same day of the year" mean?  Forget the programming.  What does it mean to you in plain English?  The 94th day of the year is the 94th day of the year, leap year or otherwise.  So that wasn't the right definition of "same day" for your purposes...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do something like the following.

If you need a date a year from now.

```
Now.Date.AddYears(-1)
```

From a specific date

```
YourDate.Date.AddYears(-1)
```

Comment: Ah, yes I realize what you mean now, you need the same effective weekday from the previous year.

Comment: exactly is that possible

Comment: I need to think about this a little. It's not a simple function you're asking about.

Comment: alright ill let you know if i make a break through